The protagonist's wife/girlfriend is killed by an injection in hotel
I watched this English movie made in color, in 2006.  The movie starts with  the protagonist who I guess must be a spy by profession, he goes into a hotel with his wife or girlfriend, and on their first night they make out. 
Next, this female companion dies and it was claimed that she was killed by some sort of virus, but the protagonist suspects that she was murdered on purpose. This is all I can recall now.

The Osterman Weekend has a spy's wife murdered by injection in bed. 

After reading the plot it seems like this is the movie, but I watched its trailer and it doesn't remind me of the movie in anyway. So, I have to watch the The Osterman Weekend to get confirmed.
